# Iis it possible to typealias the empty interface, then add functions to that alias?

Tags: go

In Go, is it possible to type alias the empty interface, then add functions to that alias?

I'd like to do something like:

```
type DbJSON interface{}
func (src *DbJSON) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(src)
}
```

Comment: Implementation should be a concrete type, implementing functions on `interface{]` makes very little sense. May be you wanted `struct{}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. Method implementations belong to a *concrete type*. The spec forbids to declare methods on interfaces or pointer to interfaces and pointer types.

[Spec: Method declaration:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)

> The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceding the method name. That parameter section must declare a single non-variadic parameter, the receiver. Its type must be a [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) type `T` or a pointer to a defined type `T`. `T` is called the receiver *base type*. **A receiver base type cannot be a pointer or interface type** and it must be defined in the same package as the method.